# Grid search Hyperparametertuning for LSTM

Tags: python, performance, lstm, hyperparameters

I get different errors when trying to implement a grid search into my LSTM model. I'm trying something very similar to [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/).

```
# train the model
def build_model(train, n_back=1, n_predict=1, epochs=10, batch_size=10, neurons=100, activation='relu', optimizer='adam'):
    # define model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, activation=activation, input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
    model.add(RepeatVector(n_outputs))
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, activation=activation, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(neurons)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)
    # fit network
    model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
    return model
```

```
#### Epochs and Batch Size
batch_size = [10, 20]
epochs = [1, 10]

# Optimizer: Select!
#### Optimizer
optimizer = ['Adam', 'Adamax'] #'SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adagrad', 'Adadelta', 'Adam', 'Adamax', 'Nadam'

#### Learning Rate and Momentum
learn_rate = [0.01, 0.2] #0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3
momentum = [0.0, 0.2, 0.9] #0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9
lr_optimizer = SGD(lr=learn_rate, momentum=momentum)

#### Tune Network Weight Initialization
init_mode = ['lecun_uniform','zero', 'he_normal'] #'uniform', 'lecun_uniform', 'normal', 'zero', 'glorot_normal', 'glorot_uniform', 'he_normal', 'he_uniform'

#### Neuron Activation Function
activation = ['relu', 'softmax'] #'softmax', 'softplus', 'softsign', 'relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid', 'hard_sigmoid', 'linear'

#### Tune Dropout Regularization
weight_constraint = [2, 3] #1, 2, 3, 4, 5
dropout_rate = [0.0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9] #0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9

#### Tune the Number of Neurons in the Hidden Layer
neurons = [100, 200] #10, 50, 100, 200
```

```
# create model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model(train, n_back, n_predict, epochs, batch_size, neurons, activation, optimizer), verbose=1)
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, optimizer=optimizer,
                  activation=activation,neurons=neurons)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = grid.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

One error for example is:

```
('Could not interpret activation function identifier:', ['relu', 'softmax'])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Are there better ways to "tune" my LSTM?

Answer (score 1):

Short:
GridSearchCV is just working 2D not 3D or in other words, just 3D and not 4D (with the time).
You have to set up your own grid search in this case.

If you have any questions regarding this you can contact me.
Hope this helped.